# How do Hero units scale with unit size in Total War: Three Kingdoms?

Tags: three-kingdoms-total-war

*Large* unit size in TW:3K has standard infantry units at 120. *Extreme* unit size has them at 240.

How do the hero units scale with this increase? Do they double in health, damage, etc. from large to extreme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly tested the difference between medium and large using custom battle.

[image: Medium Unit Size General]

[image: Large Unit Size General]

Apparently, Generals' health, attack damage and charge bonus values are scaled according to unit size.